# calculating average in python?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, while-loop

the question is:

> Ask the user how many children she has.  Input the ages for each child (ensuring that the value is a number between 0 and 100).  Calculate and output the average age of the user’s children.

and here is what I have so far:

```
child = int(input("How many children do you have?"))
count = 1
total = 0
if child > 100:
    print("Invalid!")
else:
    while count <= 11:
        n = int(input("Enter child #%s" %str(count)+ " age:"))
        count += 1
        total += n

    print("Average age:", total/child)
```

I can't set the numbers of children. for instance, when I input 3 or 7 children for the question (How many children do you have?), it still lets me input ages for 11 children. I know I have set it to <= 11 but I don't know how else to do it?? Also, this is my attempt for a `while-loop`, I still need to do it using a `for-loop`?? And does it look alright overall?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me help you by providing the right code and explaining to you how it works:

```
child = int(input("How many children do you have?"))
count = 1
total = 0
if child > 100:
    print("Invalid!")
else:
    while count <= child:
        n = int(input("Enter child #%s" %str(count)+ " age:"))
        count += 1
        total += n

print("Average age:", total/child)
```

The condition `count <= child` checks if we have taken all children in consideration or not. You could easily change it to a for loop:

```
child = int(input("How many children do you have?"))
total = 0
if child > 100:
    print("Invalid!")
else:
    for count in range(child): # This start counting from 0
        n = int(input("Enter child #%s" %str(count)+ " age:"))
        total += n

print("Average age:", total/child)
```

This loop actually repeats itself `numChildren` times, as many as we wanted it to. For some documentantion about `range` please check [this link.](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range)

Also, since you'd most probably want to have a proper input for `child` you can write the following piece of code to force the user enter a proper input:

```
child = int(input("How many children do you have?"))
count = 1
total = 0
while child > 100:
    print("Invalid!")
    child = int(input("How many children do you have?"))

while count <= child:
    n = int(input("Enter child #%s" %str(count)+ " age:"))
    count += 1
    total += n

print("Average age:", total/child
```

Comment: Very detailed, much appreciated. Now it is very clear. I was wondering how to force the user to enter number of children and now you just made it so easy. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

You answered your own question.     `while count <= 11:` is resulting to go loop for 11 times.

Replace: `while count <= 11` with `while count <=child`

Comment: Wow! I wasn't even aware. Thank you. Also, how do I get rid of the decimals in my answer?

Comment: @pimpmycamel if you have more questions (which you haven't been able to answer with a google search), you will probably have better luck by asking a new question rather than posting comments here. Questions are much more visible, while comments can easily go unnoticed. Also, if your questions are high quality, you might be able to gain reputation from votes on them, which doesn't apply to comments.

Comment: @Ivc thanks for the advice, although I cannot post each question because they are related to this specific problem. But I will take that under consideration!

Answer (score 4):

If I'm reading your problem correctly. When it asks the user for number of children you are storing it in the `child` variable and then you are using it to compare to the maximum age of the child(100). Which isn't correct.
After getting the child variable input from the user you should use a `for` loop along with the `range()` functionlike this:

```
child = int(input("How many children do you have?"))
total =0
for num in range(child):
     n = int(input("Enter child age:"))
     if n > 100:
         print "error"
     total+=n
```

Then take the total and avg it with child. The `num` variable doesn't have to be defined because Python will do it for you in the `for` loop. Hope this helps

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
while count <= 11:
```

to

```
while count <= child:
```

You are looping only 11 times, you have to loop until <= child times.

Comment: Thank you! Also, how can I let the user input # of children again if they enter more than 100 which would be invalid??

Comment: When you are checking if child are greater than 100, you can loop it instead as long as child is greater than 100 and take input again

Answer (score 2):

Use `child` instead of `11`.

To use a `for` loop, you can get rid of the `count` counter and just do `for i in range(child):`.

Answer (score 2):

Strange that none of the provided answers checks if the given number of children greater that zero. And nobody has thought that the average age is in most cases not an integer.

You have to check if `child > 0` and calculate the final result as `float`

```
child = int(input("How many children do you have?"))
count = 1
total = 0
if child <= 0 or child > 100:
    print("Invalid!")
else:
    while count <= child:
        n = int(input("Enter child #%s" %str(count)+ " age:"))
        count += 1
        total += n

    print("Average age:", float(total)/float(child))
```

Comment: That's true, I wasn't paying attention to it. Thanks for the great tip!